# Remove NULL values from multiple LEFT JOIN in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have the following tables

**ITEM1**

```
ID | NAME | GEARS | ITEM2_ID  |
-------------------------------
1  | Test | 56    | 4         |
2  | Test2| 12    | 2         |
```

**ITEM3**

```
ID | NAME | DATA  | ITEM2_ID  |
-------------------------------
1  | Test | 1     | 1         |
2  | Test7| 22    | 3         |
```

**ITEM2**

```
ID |   VALUE       |
--------------------
1  |   is simple   |  
2  |   is hard     | 
3  |   is different|
4  |   is good     |
5  |   very good   |
```

And my query

```
SELECT TOP(3) * FROM (
    SELECT ID, 
       rankTable.RANK as RANK_,
        TOTALROWS = COUNT(*) OVER() 
 FROM ITEM2
 INNER JOIN 
     CONTAINSTABLE(ITEM2, [VALUE], 'ISABOUT("good")') as rankTable
 ON ITEM2.ID = rankTable.[KEY]
) as ITEM2table

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ID, 
      NAME, 
      GEARS, 
      ITEM2_ID 
    FROM ITEM1
) as ITEM1table
ON ITEM1table.ITEM2_ID = ITEM2table.ID

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ID, 
        NAME, 
        DATA, 
        ITEM2_ID 
    FROM ITEM3
) as ITEM3table
ON ITEM3table.ITEM2_ID = ITEM2table.ID
```

and the results

[image]

How to remove (if is possible) the first row (ID = 5) using the above SQL query ? Also I want to show TOTALROWS = 1 because other row contains NULL's except first 3 columns.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to keep only the rows where either the first or the second (or both) outer join succeeds:

```
WHERE ITEM1table.ITEM2_ID IS NOT NULL 
   OR ITEM3table.ITEM2_ID IS NOT NULL
```

Some simplifications can be done on the query. No need for the nested subqueries:

```
SELECT TOP(3) 
    ITEM2table.ID, 
    rankTable.RANK as RANK_,
    TOTALROWS = COUNT(*) OVER(),
    ITEM1table.*,
    ITEM3table.*  

FROM 
        ITEM2 

    INNER JOIN 
        CONTAINSTABLE(ITEM2, [VALUE], 'ISABOUT("good")') as rankTable
    ON ITEM2.ID = rankTable.[KEY]

    LEFT JOIN 
        ITEM1  as ITEM1table
    ON ITEM1table.ITEM2_ID = ITEM2.ID

    LEFT JOIN 
        ITEM3  as ITEM3table
    ON ITEM3table.ITEM2_ID = ITEM2.ID

WHERE ITEM1table.ITEM2_ID IS NOT NULL 
   OR ITEM3table.ITEM2_ID IS NOT NULL 

ORDER BY  something                     --- you need to order by something
                                        --- if you use TOP. Unless you want 
                                        --- 3 (random) rows.
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe there's an obvious reason, but if you want to eliminate rows where the second table doesn't have a match, why are you using a left join? It seems like your first join should be an inner join and your second should be left - that would give you the results you want in this case.

Comment: My example is very simple, is a scenario, I don't know that words belongs only to a table or many table... My database has over 10000 words in table `ITEM2` and it may appears in ITEM1 or ITEM3

Comment: @Michael Swan: Simple or not, you're asking how to exclude row 1 from your results because the "middle set" of columns are NULL, and an INNER JOIN is how you do it. If your situation is more complicated, please provide some additional details about it so we can help find a solution - currently, switching the join type solves the problem as you've stated it.

Answer (score 3):

You can either use `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`, or put

```
WHERE ITEM1table.ID IS NOT NULL AND ITEM3table.ID IS NOT NULL
```

at the end of your query

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. Thanks for this.